# A WeakIdentityKeyDictionary with no keys or values of size 1?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

**Try this script in Pharo:**

```
dictionary := WeakIdentityKeyDictionary new.
key := Object new.
dictionary at: key put: 'hello'.
dictionary size. " --> 1 "
key := nil.
2 timesRepeat: [Smalltalk garbageCollect].
```

By now the dictionary should be empty. However:

```
dictionary keys isEmpty. " --> true"
dictionary values isEmpty. " --> true "
```

as expected, but

```
dictionary isEmpty. " --> false ??"
dictionary size. " --> 1 !! "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be like this by design. If you read the comments of the `WeakKeyDictionary` class (`WeakIdentityKeyDictionary`'s superclass):

> I am a dictionary holding only weakly on my keys. This is a bit dangerous since at any time my keys can go away. Clients are responsible to register my instances by WeakArray such that the appropriate actions can be taken upon loss of any keys. **As key may disappear at any time, my reported size may be greater than the number of keys encountered in iterations.**

*(emphasis mine)*

The dictionary's internal array still has the association `nil --> 'hello'`, and that's why the dictionary's `size` is 1, but `WeakIdentityKeyDictionary`'s `associationsDo:` check for `nil` key's and avoid evaluating them (see the last line):

```
associationsDo: aBlock 
    "Evaluate aBlock for each of the receiver's elements (key/value 
    associations)."

    super associationsDo: [:association | | key | 
        "Hold onto the key so it won't be collected while the block is evaluated."
        key := association key.
        key ifNotNil:[aBlock value: association]].
```

`Dictionary#associations` is based on `associationsDo:`, so that's why `dictionary associations` is also empty.

Comment: Makes sense. So, I guess that the "solution" to the (potential) inconsistency would be for the client of `#size` or `#isEmpty` to call `#finalizeValues` first...

Comment: I don't know your context, but an alternative could also be to subclass or decorate the dictionary with another class whose `size` and every other message depends on `associations`. But that may be harder - and more CPU intensive.